# How can I get my ban removed as soon as possible?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, post-ban

I got banned from Stack Overflow and after referring to Stack Overflow's help section, I edited two of my questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618636/eclipse-gives-sh-line-3-root-documents-mp3eclipse-test-mp3-test-mp3exit) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870960/i-get-the-error-error-cl-cl-h-no-such-file-or-directory-when-i-try-to-build)) to make them more specific.

I understand that [my most recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43329219/advice-on-getting-started-with-implementing-a-motion-jpeg-decoder) is vague but I don't understand how I can fix it. I only asked this question because I am a beginner and I really wanted some advice on getting started. I don't have enough knowledge at this point to make this question more specific. I know from the help section that deleting this question won't help either.

I have gone over my remaining questions and I don't see issues with them.

**What can I do at this point in time to remove my ban?**

Comment: @BSMP:  There's some value in discussing the OP's specific questions, at least.

Comment: wrt your third question, consider editing it to wipe out things related to "getting started". See [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260) for why it would better go away

Comment: @gnat Thank you for your advice. I modified my third question in order to make it more specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first two questions look *okay*, but your third question sticks out like a sore thumb.  Asking questions like, "How do I get started?" are so open-ended that it's impossible for us to delve into an answer.

We specialize at helping users out when they have a specific problem to work on.  Not knowing where to start is *unspecific*.  We're no good with those questions.

You may have to take this one on the chin.  I'm sure there are other questions which we're not seeing that are also affecting your ban threshold.  Look to improve the questions you've got to get them to attract upvotes.

Comment: I asked some questions a few months ago and those were indeed poorly written. I no longer have access to those. I have access to only one deleted question I asked about code I found on github.

Comment: @a_sid you can flag any of your questions for moderators attention and ask for list of old deleted questions.